# GCD program using Euclidean algorithm

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to do a program that uses the Euclidean algorithm to find the GCD of two numbers. The Euclidean algorithm says that you divide the big number by the small number and take that remainder and divide the original small number by the remainder, and you continue to do that until you get zero. My program prints out the remainder, and the small number, but I want to find the GCD and print out each step (every number that goes through the program).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GCD{

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        double n1;
        double n2;
        double firstOperation; 
        double smallNum;
        double nextOperation;

        System.out.println("Enter the first number (positive) ");
        n1 = reader.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the second number (positive)");
        n2 = reader.nextDouble();

        if (n1 > n2){
           smallNum = n2;
           firstOperation = n1 % n2;
           System.out.println (firstOperation);
        }
        if (n1<n2){
           smallNum = n1;
           firstOperation = n2 % n1;
           System.out.println (firstOperation);
        }
        while (firstOperation >0)
           nextOperation = smallNum % firstOperation ;
           //System.out.println(nextOperation);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: JAVA IS NOT JAVASCRIPT!!!!!!!!!

Comment: First use Int for all you variabe instead of double

Comment: Second, your while loop will run forever, because `firstOperation` never changes

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Calculating GCD of %d and %d", a, b));
    if(b == 0) {
        return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```